# How do you implement a portable JVM into your program?

Tags: jvm

So I've heard of programs that have some sort of portable JVM that runs in their program, so it can run on any computer, no matter what, with no dependencies.

How did they do that?

Comment: I never heard of a JVM running inside a program. Usually process JVMs run programs that you develop in a high level language. Actually, I'm curious about this so if you find any more information about this please let me know.

Answer (score 4):

[Avian](http://oss.readytalk.com/avian/) is designed to work this way.  You build your app as a native executable for whatever platform(s) you need to support, and that executable contains the VM, an embedded JAR containing your Java classes and resources, and any JNI code your app requires.

Answer (score 0):

If what you're looking for is have a portable version of a JRE, you can just zip your own JRE/JDK and have your program use it.

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29915255/1098603) on a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6805332/1098603).